# Have two tables next to each other while also using header and sidebar css

Tags: html, css, html-table, sidebar

I have a very simple php page that contains a header, and a nav sidebar. In the content area of the page I'm trying to get two tables to reside next to each other. Instead of on top of one another.

It seems that in their current state they go directly below the nav side bar instead of leaving every thing below the sidebar for whitespace:

http://jsfiddle.net/qgEbZ/

[image: current look]

[image: desired look]

HTML

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div id = 'headContainer'>
            <div id = 'header'>
                <?php include 'header.html'; ?>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'sideContainer'>
            <div id= 'navMain'>
                <?php include 'sidebar.html'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'content'>
            <TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Left Table</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Left Table</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Right Table</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Right Table</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

CSS

```
#sideContainer {
    float:left;
}

#navMain {
    margin-left:25px;
    color:#999999;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#headContainer {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    height: 150px;
}

#header{
    margin:0px auto;
    height: 150px;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider *not* using `table` elements for layout purposes, use semantically-relevant HTML elements to mark-up your content and CSS to style appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using TABLES for layout is bad form, you can accomplish this by simply floating your tables.

```
#content table {
    float:left;
    width:50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a class to each of the tables you have and than using CSS make than flow to the correct positions...

I did the change on your sample...

http://jsfiddle.net/qgEbZ/1/

```
<TABLE class = 'leftTable'>
 <TR>
    <TD>Left Table</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>Left Table</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE class = 'midTable'>
  <TR>
     <TD>Right Table</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
     <TD>Right Table</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

And than on CSS

```
.leftTable{
  position:absolute;
  float: left;
}
.midTable{
  position:absolute;
  float: left;
  left:100px;
}
```

BTW, you can have the same result removing tables and using divs (as suggested already by many guys :))

Comment: What's the purpose of absolute positioning here?

Comment: Actually I just put it to show him that he can put the tables exactly where he want's. But besides that it's not necessary.